# Compare value in cell with previous non-empty value in the same column and format accordingly [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm logging entries of price changes for certain products and would like to make these changes visually scannable, by formatting increases in price in red and decreases in green.

I'm playing with conditional formatting but still can't hone in on the exact formula.

What it needs to do:

- For each cell in the column, find the previous **non-empty** cell in the same column and then compare the two values and format accordingly.

Any suggestions? Thanks so much!

[image: Example of data with desired formatting]

I've tried playing with this formula but can't seem to make it do what I need:

```
=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

***Greater than pre-non-blank***

```
=len(A3)*(A3>lookup(9^9,A$1:A2))
```

***lesser than pre-non-blank***

```
=len(A3)*(A3<lookup(9^9,A$1:A2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, works a treat. It does look like magic to me if I'm honest. For example, why is `len(A3)*` necessary? Also, what does `9^9` in the `lookup` do?

Comment: 1, `len` to not highlight the blank cells and 2, 9^9 is a random big number and it is unlikely for lookup to find this number in the search range or higher value than that. so the function resorts to returning the last found value in that specific range.